# Windows Firewall Blocking Allowed Ports

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-firewall

Client is Win 7 x64 Server is Server 2008 R2

I have the following setup and having an issue with firewall that I am quite perplexed about.

Client 10.x.x.1 is trying to access active data on remote ports 1000, 10000 from server 10.x.x.2. Firewall is on the client but off on the server. All is working correctly. When firewall is enabled all data drops out to the program running on the client. There is an allow rules on the incoming for the server for ports local ports 1000, 10000. Even with this rules on the server I get the following type of log.

```
2015-11-16 13:20:08 DROP TCP 10.X.X.1 10.X.X.2 49939 10000 S 3548206488 0 8192 - - - RECEIVE
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? There are no other block rules. All other rules are for basic services such as DNS, File Sharing, AD etc.

Thanks.

EDIT 1: Ran the following

```
netstat -p tcp -ano
```

This is showing

```
TCP 10.x.x.2 10.x.x.1:10000 ESTABLISHED (PID of Server Data Program)
```

Still not passing data. Program on Client sees all connections still severed.